# Does ASP.NET MVC ViewPage or ViewUserControl allow multiple inheritence

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one Viewpage where I inherit List version of my model class to show a list of products. Now on the same page I want to create a form for which I need to use my model class properties. As I'm using a List version of model class, I'm not being able to get the properties without iterating the items in Model.
I tried creating an UserControl inheritting the model class itself and use `<%Html.RenderPartial("UserControl"); %>` in my list class. But it gives runtime error.
How to avoid this situation?? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

No you can do it by creating a composite model object containg your first model and your second one

In your page directive: `ViewPage<YouCompositeModelType>`

in your page: `<% Html.RenderPartial("YourPartialViewName", Model.YourSecondModelObject); %>`